# Flutter: Gradient with color for each edge

Tags: flutter, gradient

is it possible to draw a gradient where I can define the color for each edge (topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft and topLeft)? As you can see on the image, I have two different gradients. Now I need to combine these in the white area.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no easy solution to that in flutter, you can play around about two LinearGradients with `ShaderMask` or double container with opacity, but both will not give you robust solution:
[image]

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [
                  Colors.red,
                  Colors.green,
                ]),
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topRight,
                  end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```